# Customize Transposing data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to transpose data to another table so that this table 1 would be transposed. Please see table below.

from this **table 1**

```
                day 1           day 2           day 3           day 4   
                value   %       value   %       value   %       value   %
information 1   5694    59.72%  5694    59.72%  5694    59.72%  5678  59.55%
```

to this **table 2**

```
information 1                               
                day 1   day 2   day 3   day 4               
value           5694    5694    5694    5678                
%               59.72%  59.72%  59.72%  59.55%
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried using this =TRANSPOSE(A1:G6) but it wont show output/ tried using transpose(range) but it does not work

Comment: @yobab77 What you ask for cannot be done with a built-in function or formula. Instead you will need to write your own VBA code to perform each step. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar before using the built in formula OFFSET. Create the row and column headings as shown in red below. Then enter the three formulae as show below in the first day column.

[image: screenshot]

drag those three formulae and the day numbering across as far as you need.

As some comments have said, you'll get more and better answers if you provide details of what you've tried already and show that you've made an effort before asking the internet. For instance I might have taken the time to explain a little about how OFFSET works and how I figured out what values to give it. As it is... look it up :)